# How can multiple binary diagnostic tests be best integrated to form an overall diagnosis?

Tags: classification, biostatistics, sensitivity-specificity

I have three diagnostics tests. Each test indicates classifies an individual as either 0=ill or 1=non-sick. I assume these test are not independent.

**How can multiple binary diagnostic tests be best integrated to form an overall diagnosis?**

Comment: And how are they not independent?

Comment: How is it that the tests were binary?  What are the actual tests you are studying?  Very few medical tests are actually binary, and converting their output to binary loses an amazing amount of information.

Comment: Similar to what @John said: I understand why you'd expect the outcomes of the tests to be dependent (i.e., $P(A \cap B) \ne P(A)P(B)$), but might they be conditionally independent given the true sickness status? (I.e., $P(A \cap B \mid Sick) = P(A \mid Sick)P(B \mid Sick)$)

Answer (score 3):

*Here's a few quick thoughts, based on a general understanding of statistics. I'm not sure what's the convention in the diagnostics literature:*

If you have a gold-standard indicator of whether a person is sick or not, you could perform a logistic regression predicting whether a person is sick or not from the three diagnostic tests. You could then do a [sensitivity and specificity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity) analysis to decide which combinations of the tests were sufficient for you to make a given diagnosis.

If the component tests were originally based on continuous variables, then I'd generally use those continuous variables as predictors in the logistic regression equation. This would generally be a more powerful approach. For example, someone who is just below threshold on all three indicators may be highly likely to be sick, whereas someone is very low on two but about threshold on one, may be less likely to be sick.

If you don't have validation data, then I imagine you'd have to fall back on expert judgement above the relative efficacy of different diagnostic tests.

Comment: Thank you Jeromy for your answer, i have a gold-standard. in fact i want to take a decision to accept or not that patient is ill thank to the results of three tests,but these tests are not independent and i want that my test was better than one test alone. (sorry for my english)

Comment: I don't see where sensitivity and specificity add anything over examining predicted probabilities from the combined model.  Plus they are in backwards information order.